# SQL sum with Group By of subquery max

Tags: sql, subquery

I have a GL summary table for inventory.  It has multiple rows for each item(last month period that the item changes).  I can easily get the current value of the sum (qty*price) by inner join (select max(post-date).    So the valuation is sum(qty )So if you want the valuation for say post period 202103, you would take the max(post-date) for each partnumber and sum it togeher.  For 202103 it would be PartA = 10, PartB 62 and PartC 12.  If I wanted to get it for post period 202012 then it would be partA 14, PartB 62 and PartC 12.  Essentially uusing the max date of 202012 for PartA.  So i have the query for doing the max for the entire table (most up to date).  But how would I go about it to get it for say each period.  I've tried various group by in the subquery and everything else, but cant seem to make this work.

```
part#  qty post_date
PartA  23  202004
PartB  55  202004
PartC  12  202004
PartA  20  202006
PartB  62  202007
PartA  14  202012
PartA  12  202102
PartA  10  202103
```

---

```
select
    sum(qty)
from
    invtable inv
INNER JOIN (
    Select
        max(post_date)
    from
        invtable inv2
    WHERE
        post_date < 202103
    GROUP BY
        partnumber
) as t2 
    ON t2.partnuumber = inv.partnumber
    and t2.post_date = inv.post_date
```

Ideally I want something like the following

```
202004 90
202006 87
202007 94
202012 88
202102 86
202103 84
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  If I cant get it to output this way, I guess I could programmatically run each period and dump it to a table and then pull from there.

Comment: your question is not clear , try to rephrase it and provide better sample data and desired output and explain it , your explanation doesn't link with sample data

Comment: Leaving the cost column off "for clarity" definitely does not clarify anything if the results depends on the column.

Comment: Why is post_date not a full date value?

Comment: What database are you using? I am not sure any variety of SQL could accomplish this alone. I would most likely go with the programmatic approach.

Comment: I edited to just say sum the qty which will accomplish the same thing.  

Using a progress db which is SQL92.  Though j could export to Postgres but at that point I could probably programmatically export to another table to accomplish the same. Though I prefer to get a suitable group by. 

Post date is not full date. It’s essentially the year and month of the GL post date.  I can definitely get the latest valuation.  I just can’t get the sum value at each of the post dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this in `mysql`. Below is the query. Please see if you can change or use this according to your database.

```
-- to find the sum of qty 
select
    finalT2.post_date, sum(finalT1.qty)
from
    invtable finalT1
    join 
    (
      -- for each post date -> find the max of post date for each part
      select
        t2.post_date, t1.part, max(t1.post_date) as max_post_date
      from
        invtable t1
        join 
        (  -- group to find the list of post_date(s)
           select
         post_date
           from
         invtable
           group by
         post_date
         ) t2 on t1.post_date <= t2.post_date
       group by
         t2.post_date, t1.part
    ) finalT2 on finalT1.post_date = finalT2.max_post_date and finalT1.part = finalT2.part
group by
    finalT2.post_date
```

Output Image - [image]

**Query output in Fiddle for reference :**
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=18657bfb3ec0f8d4826a8c940ecc9941